# Get current user more information

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using `.NET Core` with `C#` application and there I have integrated the Azure AD authentication. It means any Azure AD user can be logged in to this application. Now at someplace, I want to display the City, State, Country and some other fields value of current logged in user. For that, I have used [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview), but I am not able to get the details successfully. I got an error `Request_ResourceNotFound`. I used below `C#` code to get the data for current Logged in user.

```
var clientId = "<CLIENT_ID>"; // I have used my application client id here
var secret = "<CLIENT_SECRET>"; // I have used my client secret here
var domain = "<DOMAIN>"; // I have used domain here
var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain}/");
var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credentials);

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.AccessToken);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}));

var user = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Request()
    .GetAsync(); // Error at this line
```

But it throws an below error when I used `graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync()`

> Error: Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
>
> Message: Resource 'XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Have anyone faced this kind of error earlier, Can anyone suggest how to get the data for currently logged-in User using Microsoft Graph in C#?

Comment: There is no "me" if you acquire a token with client credentials. There is no user involved. You need to get a user by id or user principal name.

Comment: @juunas thanks for your quick reply, Can you please share some code snippet to get the user by id using Graph API?

Answer (score 5):

You're using Client Credentials so there *isn't* a "currently logged-in User". It is actually the entire point of Client Credentials, authenticating an application *without* a user.

When using Client Credentials, you need to explicitly specify the User `id` or `userPrincipalName`:

```
var user = await graphServiceClient
    .Users["alias@domain.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```